# Default value of variable in bash

Tags: bash

What is the default value of a variable like `$y` in bash scripting?

I want to perform the sum of `n` input numbers that is why I needed this.

Comment: It's very easy to try.

Comment: The default value in arithmetic context is even explicitly discussed in the man page section about arithmetic contexts.

Comment: How i can try, will you tell me? Thanks for corrections.

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
echo $y
```

this will show empty (null string) as the default value.
However, to set a default for a BASH variable, the syntax is:

```
VAR=${1:-DEFAULT}
```

This sets VAR with the value of 1st Arg to the script, if not available sets with DEFAULT

Answer (score 1):

After `bash` manual:

> A shell variable that is null or unset evaluates to 0 when referenced
>   by name without using the  parameter expansion  syntax.

So:

```
$ echo $x $y $z

$ ((x++))
$ echo $x
1
$ echo $((y+z+3))
3
```